# ERROR:file_io_win.cc(181)] CreateFile C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir8672_746580622\Crashpad\settings.dat

Tags: microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

Getting this issue while executing the automation on Edge using Selenium. We are creating machines using docker. Getting below error

**ERROR:file_io_win.cc(181)] CreateFile C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir8672_746580622\Crashpad\settings.dat: The system cannot find the path specified.**

Web Driver -100,
Edge version - 100,
OS: Windows 10

Found a few references on the web but those are without any solution.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't find the cause of the problem with the information you provided. If possible, can you provide steps to reproduce the problem and corresponding sample code?

Comment: Actually, this is running through our automation, and Edge is started by automation itself using the Edge driver.